# SQL is it possible to use AND/OR with HAVING clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have these tables:

```
Products
--------
Product ID | Quantity
```

AND

```
OrdersLines 
-----------
Product ID | Amount --(multiple lines with the same ID)
```

I'm using this select:

```
 SELECT 
 P.ProductID,
 P.Quantity,
 SUM(OL.Amount) AS Ordered
 FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
 INNER JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL ON OL.ProductID = P.ProductID
 GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Quantity
 HAVING P.Quantity > SUM(OL.Amount)
```

The select works properly if `ProductID` is used in both tables.
However, if `ProductID` is not used in `OrdersLines` table or `Amount` in that table is `Null` - such rows are not included.

Comment: Based on the title of your post, yes,  a `HAVING` clause can use `AND`, `OR` or any other operators you would use in a `WHERE` clause. The only caveat is the `HAVING` clause has to operate on aggregates (like `sum()`, `max()`, etc.)

Comment: So major question is if that solves my problem :)

Comment: Assuming your problem is more than just the title of the post, what exactly IS your problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Ok, I will tell you what i want it to do. Basically, It has to select every row from Products table and exclude rows where sum(OrdersLines.Amount) is larger then Products.Quantity for the given Product ID.

Comment: Odd that does not work.  I would put in a ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to join across tables but always need to include records from one side of the join or the other, then you need to use one of the `OUTER JOIN`s as opposed to the `INNER JOIN` in your SQL.  If you want to include a record from your `atbl_Sales_Products` even when there may be no matching record in the `atbl_Sales_OrderLines` with the same `ProductID` then you should use a `LEFT JOIN`.

As mentioned in the comments you can use any operators you use in a `WHERE` clause with a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid comment. If i remove line "HAVING P.Quantity > SUM(OL.Amount)" and change to LEFT JOIN - i get a table with all rows from Products table and summed quantities from OrdersLines. Still, no filter for rows where sum of amount (in OrdersLines) is higher than Products.Quantity.

Comment: I think he's saying use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, as well as keep your `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```html
SELECT 
 P.ProductID,
 P.Quantity,
 SUM(OL.Amount) AS Ordered
FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL 
ON P.ProductID = OL.ProductID
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Quantity
HAVING SUM(OL.Amount) IS NULL
OR P.Quantity > SUM(Ol.Amount)
```

Additional OR statement solved my problem.